# react bootstrap toast typescript error for position

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-bootstrap

Hi I am trying to create a component that returns a react bootstrap toast and toast container but am getting a typescript error.

```
const Notification = (props: {
variant: string,
header: string,
message: string,
position: string
}) => {
const [show, setShow] = useState(true);


return (
    <ToastContainer
      className="mt-4 pt-5"
    //   position={"top-center"}
      position={props.position}
      style={{ zIndex: 1 }}
    >
      <Toast
        onClose={() => setShow(false)}
        show={show}
        delay={7000}
        autohide
        bg={props.variant}
      >
        <Toast.Header closeButton={false}>
          <strong className="text-center">{props.header}</strong>
        </Toast.Header>
        <Toast.Body className="text-white text-center">{props.message}</Toast.Body>
      </Toast>
    </ToastContainer>
)
}
```

So I pass in

```
<Notification
    variant={"success"}
    header={"Success"}
    message={"Item successfully added to cart."}
    position={"top-center"}
  />
```

Everything works like props.message, props.variant, etc. For some reason though I get the following error for position.

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ToastPosition | undefined'.ts(2322)
> ToastContainer.d.ts(5, 5): The expected type comes from property 'position' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Omit<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>, "ref"> & { ...; }, BsPrefixProps<...> & ToastContainerProps> & BsPrefixProps<...> & ToastContainerProps & { ...; }'
> (property) ToastContainerProps.position?: ToastPosition | undefined

The code still works (it gets "top-center" from the props and places it correctly) but it gives a type error. I get that it is saying it can't be a string or undefined. I don't see why this case is different than the bg={props.variant} though. In both cases there is a default value, and it is being changed to the prop. I even tried putting in a
position={props.position ? props.position : "top-center"} thinking that might fix it but it still has the same error.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. It's word soup. Don't add tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `position` in `ToastContainer` is `ToastPosition | undefined` and not `string`.

To fix it replace `position: string` with `position?: ToastPosition` in type declartion of Notification component. The question mark makes the prop optional thus adding `undefined`.

You can import ToastPosition as follow: `import ToastContainer, { ToastPosition } from "react-bootstrap/ToastContainer";`

The line "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ToastPosition | undefined'" says the same thing.

Comment: Thanks I did not know about having ToastPosition as a type. So that got rid of the error on the position= line. But I get an error at position?: ToastPosition saying cannot find ToastPosition

Comment: Its imported from react-bootstrap/ToastContainer too. I added it above in the answer.

Comment: Ah thank you! Marked it as solved.